# Handbook or guide for space travel in the future

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book around 2009, I borrowed it from a library and I can't remember the title or author.

- It was a small blue book.
- I remember that the author was Scandinavian (possibly German)
- It was like a handbook or guide for space travel and was set in the
  future.
- There were lots of small stories told about experiences in space.

  - One story was about a writer who was explaining that his occupation
    was futile as all the possible combinations of letters and words had
    already been published.
  - Another told of how people leaving for space were allowed a small
    number of glass containers to fill as memories of Earth, you could bring anything you wanted but it had to fit in these containers. Examples were given of things that people brought; the one that stuck with me was someone that sat in their garden and watched the sunset with one of their containers and so they brought the sunset with them to space.

Comment: The Universal Library? - http://eduscapes.com/history/contemporary/UniversalLibrary.PDF

Comment: If so, http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178137 shows a blue cover. Dunno about the content of the stories.

Comment: I don't think it was The Universal Library, but the story is very similar to the part I remember. Thank you

Comment: I can't find my copy to check, but some of this sounds similar to my recollections of ["Handbook for Space Pioneers"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0715378279/?tag=stackoverfl08-20)